# How to avoid using $root on component's templates?

Tags: angularjs, components, angularjs-rootscope

I'm trying to check if a user has a specific role from my `component`'s `template`.

For example, this could be my session service :

```
function Session() {
    'ngInject';

    var userRoles = {};

        ...

    function hasRole(role) {
        if(userRoles[role]) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    return {
      getUserRoles: getUserRoles,
      setUserRoles: setUserRoles,
      hasRole: hasRole
    };
};
```

I'll then assin my service to the $rootScope in my `.run()` method :

```
$rootScope.session = Session;
```

But it seems that I cannot access my session service from my component's template :

```
<div ng-show="session.hasRole('TEST')">
   Hi, {{session.getUserRoles() | json}}
</div>
```

It only works when I specify the $root service :

```
<div ng-show="$root.session.hasRole('TEST')">
   Hi, {{$root.session.getUserRoles() | json}}
</div>
```

Why is that ? And how can I avoid using `$root`, to access my `$rootScope`'s services when using angular's `component` architecture ?

Comment: A component's scope (in contrast to directives) is always isolate, you cannot use it, and you shouldn't. Why do you want to avoid using `$root` anyway?

Comment: Use a service instead of `$rootScope`. Assign value to that service in run block

Comment: @user1238367 I would be using it in all my views. And since I've read that it is considered to be bad practice,I thought I would ask for a better alternative.

charlietfl, I'll have to pass it to every single one of my controllers and that's what I'm trying to avoid in the first place.